# How can get parent of a child that has a specific value in a deep nested array of object and array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a deep nested array of objects and arrays in my project and I want to find a object that has a value in nested array child of itself; Below is a simple example of my json (For a better understanding, I simplified it a bit) :

```json
sections: [
            {
                id: 'e9904688-fd8a-476d-8f46-930bc4d888d1',
                name: 'sec-e9904688-fd8a-476d-8f46-930bc4d888d1',
                rows: [
                    {
                        id: '2f1bc178-d2bf-4283-ae9c-868513af789f',
                        name: 'row-2f1bc178-d2bf-4283-ae9c-868513af789f',
                        cols: [
                            {
                                id: 'adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114',
                                name: 'col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114',
                                isEmpty: false,
                                size: {
                                    lg: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    md: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    sm: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    xs: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    xxs: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }
                                },
                                controles: [
                                    {
                                        id : '37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6' , 
                                        name : 'control name' , 
                                        type : 'control type' , 
                                        options : [
                                            {} , 
                                            {}
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
            {
                id: 'f3f5522c-0b7f-4d6f-84a7-50cce4e92775',
                name: 'sec-f3f5522c-0b7f-4d6f-84a7-50cce4e92775',
                rows: [
                    {
                        id: '8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994',
                        name: 'row-8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994',
                        cols: [
                            {
                                id: 'e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa',
                                name: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa',
                                isEmpty: false,
                                size: {
                                    lg: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    md: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    sm: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    xs: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                                    xxs: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }
                                },
                                controles: [
                                    {
                                        id : '37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6' , 
                                        name : 'control name' , 
                                        type : 'control type' , 
                                        options : [
                                            {} , 
                                            {}
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

for example I want find an object that its child has col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa value (in size in i key and I want its parent that's mean a object of cols array with name equal of searched characters)

Answer (score 0):

You have to based the seach on your object structure. In your case it could look like this.

```js
const sections = [
  {
      id: 'e9904688-fd8a-476d-8f46-930bc4d888d1',
      name: 'sec-e9904688-fd8a-476d-8f46-930bc4d888d1',
      rows: [
          {
              id: '2f1bc178-d2bf-4283-ae9c-868513af789f',
              name: 'row-2f1bc178-d2bf-4283-ae9c-868513af789f',
              cols: [
                  {
                      id: 'adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114',
                      name: 'col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114',
                      isEmpty: false,
                      size: {
                          lg: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          md: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          sm: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          xs: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          xxs: { i: "col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }
                      },
                      controles: [
                          {
                              id : '37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6' ,
                              name : 'control name' ,
                              type : 'control type' ,
                              options : [
                                  {} ,
                                  {}
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      id: 'f3f5522c-0b7f-4d6f-84a7-50cce4e92775',
      name: 'sec-f3f5522c-0b7f-4d6f-84a7-50cce4e92775',
      rows: [
          {
              id: '8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994',
              name: 'row-8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994',
              cols: [
                  {
                      id: 'e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa',
                      name: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa',
                      isEmpty: false,
                      size: {
                          lg: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          md: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          sm: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          xs: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 },
                          xxs: { i: "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa", x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }
                      },
                      controles: [
                          {
                              id : '37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6' ,
                              name : 'control name' ,
                              type : 'control type' ,
                              options : [
                                  {} ,
                                  {}
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
];

const searchString = "col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa";

const foundItem = sections.find(
  section => section.rows.find(
    row => row.cols.find(
      col => Object.keys(col.size).find(size => col.size[size].i === searchString)
    )
  )
);

console.log(foundItem.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , But this json is a simple type of my json ,this may be very nested than this is and I can not sure with what key can search to find

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but here is a possible solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Note that all parents are present in the `parents` array, so pick whichever one you desire.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const sections = [{"id":"e9904688-fd8a-476d-8f46-930bc4d888d1","name":"sec-e9904688-fd8a-476d-8f46-930bc4d888d1","rows":[{"id":"2f1bc178-d2bf-4283-ae9c-868513af789f","name":"row-2f1bc178-d2bf-4283-ae9c-868513af789f","cols":[{"id":"adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","name":"col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","isEmpty":false,"size":{"lg":{"i":"col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"md":{"i":"col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"sm":{"i":"col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"xs":{"i":"col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"xxs":{"i":"col-adad03c8-60f3-4db1-8c6c-a125bbd7f114","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4}},"controles":[{"id":"37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6","name":"control name","type":"control type","options":[{},{}]}]}]}]},{"id":"f3f5522c-0b7f-4d6f-84a7-50cce4e92775","name":"sec-f3f5522c-0b7f-4d6f-84a7-50cce4e92775","rows":[{"id":"8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994","name":"row-8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994","cols":[{"id":"e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","name":"col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","isEmpty":false,"size":{"lg":{"i":"col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"md":{"i":"col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"sm":{"i":"col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"xs":{"i":"col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4},"xxs":{"i":"col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa","x":1,"y":0,"w":12,"h":4}},"controles":[{"id":"37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6","name":"control name","type":"control type","options":[{},{}]}]}]}]}];

objectScan(['**[*].name'], {
  filterFn: ({ value, parents }) => {
    if (value === 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa') {
      console.log(parents[2]);
    }
  }
})(sections);
// => { id: '8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994', name: 'row-8263d5fc-4445-4243-8cb2-3853b3918994', cols: [ { id: 'e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', name: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', isEmpty: false, size: { lg: { i: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }, md: { i: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }, sm: { i: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }, xs: { i: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 }, xxs: { i: 'col-e0a56604-196a-4dcc-a04e-a56968a2f8aa', x: 1, y: 0, w: 12, h: 4 } }, controles: [ { id: '37619580-6ba6-4058-a39b-2d57d23007d6', name: 'control name', type: 'control type', options: [ {}, {} ] } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)